# How can I use the numbers to the right of a decimal point in a double?

Tags: c

My apologies if this question was asked already (I'm assuming that since it's a rather simple question and not because I didn't try to find it first!).

What I was trying to do is build a double number one char at a time.
The numbers to the left were easy with the line `num = num * 10 + (c - '0');`

`/*num being the number built so far and c being the char added*/`

but then doing something like

`num = (double)((int)num) + ( (num%1)*10 + (c - '0') )/decDigits; //decDigits is the number of digits(including the new one) to the right of the decimal point`

wouldn't work because apparently you can't use the % operator on a double.

What'd be the right way to achieve the above?

Comment: Is this an XY-Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Did you look at `strtod()`?

Comment: Hmm, not familiar with that one, I'll have to look into it.
And I don't think it's an XY problem since the method given in the answer is basically what I was trying to do corrected (that's if I understood the XY thing right at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to convert a double to a string, or a string to a double? It looks like the latter, and I don’t think you should be using the `%` operator in that case at all. Starting at `0.1`, multiply each digit’s value by what’s appropriate for its place.

It’s easier to explain in C, though:

```
char c;
double result = 0.0;

/* The part before the decimal place */
while ((c = *s++) && c != '.') {
    result = result * 10.0 + (c - '0');
}

/* The part after the decimal place */
if (c == '.') {
    double m = 0.1;
    s++;

    while ((c = *s++)) {
        result += m * (c - '0');
        m *= 0.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to convert a string to a double :) Reason I'm doing it char by char is that I can't allocate any memory in this task. And your answer did indeed do the trick, so tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator is not defined for floating points. If you are trying to use `num%1` to extract the decimal part of `num`, you should instead try something like this:

```
double num_dec = num - floor(num);
```